# how to get the size of an ion-col in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to get the ion-col size in angular 8

My code works very well if I want the size of a `<div>` but doesn't work if I want from `<ion-col>`.

I get this error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Someone have an idea if it's possible to do it and how to do ?

Thanks you very much for help

**CSS Code:**

```
div {
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**TS Code:**

```
  @ViewChild('container', { static: true }) container: ElementRef;

  getInfo() {
    const width = this.container.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const height = this.container.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    console.log('width : ', width, ' + ', height);
  }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>

      <ion-col size="6" (click)="getInfo()" #container>
        <div></div>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: @MaihanNijat stackblitz does not support ionic 4 with angular 8

Comment: The way of programming in IONIC 4 is different. The file structure is not the same

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<ion-col>` is not a `ElementRef`

You should have something like :

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ElementRef}) container: ElementRef;
```

And then :

```
this.container.nativeElement.offsetHeight
```

Comment: It looks to be more like `@ViewChild('container', {static: false }) container: IonCol;` But  after I'm lost to find width and height.

Comment: what is the output of console.log(this.container.eRef) ?

Answer (score 0):

this work for me in ionic 5

**TS CODE**

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ElementRef}) container: ElementRef;



  getInfo() {
    const width = this.container.el.offsetWidth; // instead of this.container.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const height = this.container.el.offsetHeight;
    console.log('width : ', width, ' + ', height);
  }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" #container>
        .....
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```